# Application self-closing on demand

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a console application that needs to be able to stay open listening to commands that are sent to it from a communication module.

I managed to do that by adding this :

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem I'm having is that, through the communication I want to able someone to send me a command telling me to close the application.

Those two informations collides and I'm stuck on how to do it properly.

Comment: Only a comment.  Change it to a WPF application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered this approach?

```
public static void Main(...)
{
    while(true)
    {
        // do job

        if(exit condition)
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I could get rid of ReadLine(). The thing is, my Main application just creates an object and this objects only reacts to events from the communication. I'll give it a careful try anyway...

Comment: I chose a sligthly different way to do it but it indeed works. Thank you very much!